# My code doesn't work in Chrome or Safari

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari

I have been working on creating a website for a family company. It is mostly created, however I cannot get it to work in Chrome or Safari. Specifically, the links to go from page to page do not work. When clicking on the tabs on the left side, or the logo at the top, you should be directed to a different page. This works perfectly on IE. However, they do not work at all in the other 2. I have looked and looked and can't find a reason why. If anybody could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

I realize that the tabs are not uniform in Chrome or Safari as they are in IE. That is just not as important an issue to fix at the moment.

Here is the HTML for one of the pages so you can see what I have done and where I have messed up.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            BERK Consulting LLC
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            a:link {color:white; }
            a:visited{color:white; }
            a:hover {color:white; }
            body {background-color:#F2E8DE}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Main" style="padding-left:150px; position: absolute; width: 800px;">
            <p style="font-size: 18pt; text-align: justify; padding-top: 200px; padding-left: 200px;">
            BERK was founded on the desire to remove the bureaucracy, complexity, and hidden agendas from consultancy.  When you deal with BERK, you’re dealing directly with the expertise, not a salesperson or a subcontracting agency. <br /> <br />

Our down-to-earth approach combined with extensive 'in the seat' supply chain expertise allows us to advise you on key supply chain evolution decisions, allowing you to maintain focus on managing your business. <br /> <br />

We have eliminated the green beans from our team so that we can establish sustainability in your team and at an affordable rate. 
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: right; font-size: 20pt;"> <strong>
...Securing the Last Piece® <br />
                <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/269236?trk=tyah" target="_blank"> <img src="http://berkllc.com/images/LinkedIn2.png" alt="Follow Us" style="float:right;" width="150px" /> </a>
            </strong> </p>
        </div>
        <div id="Tabs" style="background-color:#502800; text-align:right; width:280px; padding-bottom:400px; padding-top:50px; padding-left:20px;">
        <a href="index.html" style="padding-left:175px;"> <img src="http://berkllc.com/images/BERKPic1.jpg" alt="BERK" /> </a>
            <p style="font-size:11pt; padding-top:50px; ">
            <span style="font-family:'Copperplate Gothic Bold'; ">
            <a href="index.html" style="color: black; background-color:#F2E8DE; padding-left:93px; padding-right:88px; padding-top:8px; padding-bottom:8px"> Home </a> <br /> <br />
            <a href="BERKWhoWeAre.html" style="background-color:#1F497D; padding-left:62px; padding-right:62.5px; padding-top:8px; padding-bottom:8px"> Who We Are </a> <br /> <br />
            <a href="BERKWhatWeDo.html" style="background-color:#1F497D; padding-left:62px; padding-right:63px; padding-top:8px; padding-bottom:8px"> What We Do </a> <br /> <br />
            <a href="BERKWhoWeveHelped.html" style="background-color:#1F497D; padding-left:36px; padding-right:37px; padding-top:8px; padding-bottom:8px"> Who We've Helped </a> <br /> <br />
            <a href="BERKOurNetwork.html" style="background-color:#1F497D; padding-left:57.5px; padding-right:57px; padding-top:9px; padding-bottom:9px"> Our Network </a> <br /> <br />
             <a href="BERKWhatAreYouMissing.html" style="background-color:#1F497D; padding-left:23px; padding-right:22px; padding-top:8px; padding-bottom:8px">What Are You Missing </a> <br /> <br />
            <a href="BERKContactUs.html" style="background-color:#1F497D; padding-left:66px; padding-right:65px; padding-top:8px; padding-bottom:8px"> Contact Us </a> <br />
            </p>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div id="blank" style="width:100%; padding-top:1px;">
        </div>
        <div id="Legal1" style="background-color:#1F497D; position: absolute; padding-top:125px; width:994px; text-align:center;">
        <table id="Legal2" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; font-size:8pt; color:white; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" cellpadding="10px">
            <tr>
                <th  style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='index.html'">
                Home
                </th>
                <th style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='BERKContactUs.html'">
                Contact Us
                </th>
                <th style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='BERKDisclaimers.html'">
                Legal Disclaimers
                </th>
                <th style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='BERKTrademark.html'">
                Trademark/Privacy
                </th>
                <th style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="location.href='BERKSitemap.html'">
                Site Map
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p style="text-align:center; font-size:6pt; color:white;">
        © 2009 BERK Consulting, LLC. All Rights Reserved.
        </p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: inline styles, no shorthand, and tables. you didn't make this in Word, by chance?

Comment: The web developer's mantra: "If it works in IE, but not the other browsers, your code is wrong.

Comment: I did not write this in Word. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sloppy but add

```
z-index: 900;position: relative;
```

to the style for:

```
<div id="Tabs" style="background-color:#502800; text-align:right; width:280px; padding-bottom:400px; padding-top:50px; padding-left:20px;z-index: 900;position: relative;">
```

and add

```
z-index: 1;
```

to the styles for

```
<div id="Main" style="padding-left:150px; position: absolute; width: 800px;z-index: 1;">
```

On an unrelated note I would recommend giving [this site](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/1-introduction-to-the-web-standards-cur/#toc) or [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/) a visit if you want to learn good practices and style for html/css/javascript.

Comment: I would NOT reccommend w3Schools for learning good practices. See: http://www.w3fools.com/.

Comment: fair enough. put dev.opera in front of it. w3schools is generally fine for a starting point though so i'll just leave that there. And based on that markup I don't think w3schools is going to hurt :-)

Comment: Very true. The MDN is another decent resource (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML), although virtually any resource would indeed be helpful in improving the OP's code. :)

Comment: @CmdrMoozy I have no problems with w3schools despite anything w3fools has to say.

Comment: I belive it has gotten better in the last few years, but I would still very much argue that resources like SE and the MDN are much more trustworthy in general.

Comment: @CmdrMoozy - I totally agree with that.

Comment: @CmdrMoozy Seconding that.

Comment: I appreciate the help Matthew. As well as the links to helpful resources in future. As has been pointed out, I'm terrible at this.

Comment: hey @user2529787, we all start somewhere :-) Trust me, I made html much sloppier than this when I started out! If this solution works, don't forget to click the checkmark on the answer to mark this question answered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your "Main" div is covering up the links. And just as I start typing this, I'm called away. In any case, do not trust IE to do this right. Trust Chrome first.